# Is function with finite amount of $\Phi_x(x+1)$ occurrences Turing computable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability

I'm studying for my exam from Logic and Computability and we have to face following kind of examples:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
         \ 1 &\text{if }\Phi_x(x+1)\!\downarrow\text{ and }x\leq50\\
         \ 0 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Unfortunatelly I'm not really clear on how to tackle those. $\Phi_x$ is the $x$-th computable function, thus it's also Turing computable. This implies, there exists a TM (we have $N$ of them) which halts and returns the output.

The task is to determine whether it's computable. In order to prove it we either provide an informal algorithm to show it's computable or a formal proof that it's not. Can any of you solve this example?

If $f(x)$ is computable, then $\Phi_x$ needs to halt for every $x \in\{1, \dots, 51\}$. However $\Phi_x$ could be undefined on one of the elements from $\{1, \dots, 51\}$ and keep looping forever.

At the other hand, there is an upper bound on $x$, which indicates its computability.

Please, can you show me the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Let $S = \{ x \vert f(x) = 1 \}$. What are the possible values of $|S|$?

Comment: The set of all values at which the f(x) halts. Then the same set can be expressed as S = { x | phi(x) Halts }. Therefore there exists a computable function which can enumerate such a set S, thus the f is computable. Is this argumentation completely off?

Comment: Before you consider the computability aspects, you need to read the question more carefully. $\Phi_x$ does _not_ need to halt for every $x\in\{1, \dots, 51\}$. $\Phi_x$ only needs to halt for input $x+1$; i.e., you only need $\Phi_1(2), \Phi_2(3), \dots, \Phi_{50}(51)$ to halt (and $\Phi_0(1)$ if you can have $x=0$. Also, you say "there exists a TM (we have $N$ of them)" -- what's $N$? There are infinitely many Turing machines.

Comment: @SimeonKredatus No, the set $S$ is the set of values $x$ for which $f(x)=1$: that's how it was defined. You need to read definitions more carefully.

Comment: By $N$ I meant countably infinite set of them (there is bijection to the set of natural numbers). So that means, there exists a TM which halts and gives a result for $\forall x$ $\Phi_x (x+1)$ from your enumeration, thus each $\Phi_x$ needs to halt only for 1 input, and we can always find such a TM. Do I slowly converge to the right reasoning?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Rule of thumb: Functions of the form "if TM with ... does not halt, output x" are *probably* not computable. Except if they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute this function using a table of size 51. More generally, if $f$ is a function which differs from a computable function $g$ on a finite number of inputs, then $f$ is computable as well. In our case, $g$ is the constant zero function, which is trivially computable.

Comment: Note bene: *we* don't know the content of this table. But we know one of all the tables of this size is the right one, which is quite enough.